# personal document management system

Tags: gui, web, remote-management, documents

I'm looking for a personal document management system that would:

- track changes in documents in a configured directory tree
- save new files to a content repository (thus allowing of their versioning)
- offer some kind of web gui for browsing the repository - ideally it would allow tracking changes in documents etc

The files I'd like it to support are:

- microsoft word files (doc, docx, xls)
- open office files
- pdf files
- txt files

I've looked through a couple of such systems (DMS-grade) but haven't noticed them having the autonomous scanning option. What I'd like to have is a unobtrusive solution that wouldn't require users to upload documents through web gui. All the versioning, backing up stuff should be transparent to them. Only if they were actually interested in downloading the older version they would fire up the web gui.

Any comments and suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try dropbox or box.net or some other similar solutions. They are not only focusing on sync but also add on features like versioning