# Document Management System for Linux

Tags: linux, files, multimedia, file-management

So I got a problem and I hope someone knows the answer.
Basically I am looking for a DMS (document management system) for my music and movies. I have a huge amount of files, currently in folders but this doesn't work anymore. Wikipedia told me that the term DMS is used slightly different in German than in English so to clarify my point see the requirements below.

What I want to do is this:

- Store my music and videos on the filesystem
- Have a software to manage meta data and location of those files
- Search for tags, categories etc. that are related to my files

I have something like a software in mind, which does this management maybe using a database.

**Please note:**

- I have neither Dropbox nor git or anything similar in mind. I need no version control and no synchronization. I just want to have a centralized solution do manage that data.
- I don't want a solution only focused on music or videos, I would like to find a solution to manage any kind of files.

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35793/personal-document-management-system) during my research, but I would prefer not to use a web-based solution, neither do I need a server. The software may be client software, although a server client structure would not be a problem.

**Suggestions so far:**

- [CouchPotato](https://couchpota.to/)
- [Kodi aka XBMC](https://kodi.tv/)
- [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/)

*I also found [this](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20101114192433367/DocumentManagementSystems.html) after I knew what exactly to look for. I don't have the time to test these systems, but there may be a good solution. Maybe someone following this has the possibility to test one or more and give some feedback here.*

I will try to improve this question continuously while getting your feedback. If something remains unclear please ask.

Thanks in advance for any useful information and hints!

Comment: do you have to manage only music and video files or documents too?

Comment: Clarified that just now. My use case is movies and music but I am looking for a solution that is independent of the file type.

Answer (score 1):

For organising your movie collection and automatically adding XBMC-compatible XML metadata files, I'd highly recommend CouchPotato. Then, depending on what you want out of your viewing experience, I'd recommend either XBMC for customisability, or its closed-source derivative, Plex, for appearance and ease of use by less technical viewers.

For music, check out Banshee - that's the best Linux-compatible music UI (the closest to foobar2000) I've found (and I've tried a lot!) without going all-out with some headless setup. You could also try Headphones (which is in the same vein as CouchPotato for movies, and Sonarr / SickBeard / SickRage for TV shows), though I haven't used it in a while and am not sure how well it can organise an existing library. On a side-note, I do recommend the Spotify Linux beta too, even if just for discovery.

Whilst most of these have server components, you can install them directly to your PC and use from there.

**Edit:** Considering your revised question, I've looked through the options you presented. If you're after an open source DMS, then [OpenKM](http://www.openkm.com/en/community.html) looks like a good choice for you - supported, modern, and desktop-based.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's not the one I am looking for but you made me see where my question is unclear and I will look into some tools you suggest.

Comment: No problem. I am happy to elaborate upon clarification.

Comment: If the downloading part of some of them is putting you off, I have recommended them based on my experience with their management of an existing collection, as that is where I understood your need to be.

Comment: To be honest I prefer some already packaged solutions, although there don't seem to any. Hopefully this question gets some attention and maybe someone can share more experience.

Comment: What do you mean by "already packaged"?

Comment: I mean I prefer something from the official repositories due to simple management via apt-get or yum. But I think for this case there will be no such option. Specifically for what I have in mind.