# Find a suite Linux open source document management system

Tags: linux-mint, software-rec

I'm looking for a Linux open source **document management system (DMS)**. Ideally I would like to install a Server on my workstation `Linux Mint`.

What I need from this system is:

- write wiki page to contain information;
- store some document;
- I prefer a web interface but it is not essentially;

What is not important:

- it is not important that it supports version control of the document.

I have found the links below:

- [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277838/document-management-system-for-linux) suggests `OpenKM` but the link was written in 2016.
- [this link](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-document-management-systems-for-linux/) speaks about many of this system (`Alfresco`, `OpenKM`, and so on).

I'm here to ask if someone, happy of one **DMS** open source for Linux, can suggest it to me.
I hope I have been clear about my needs. Don't hesitate to ask me more details.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use redmine a ton.

https://www.redmine.org/

It's primary use is an issue tracker.  But it could also be used for project pages, project planning, document library, wiki, or source code repository.

Comment: Oldskool! Nice.

Comment: There's also many other wikis you can set up

Comment: @Stewart Thanks for you answer, I'll check if **redmine** is useful for my needs...